# First time using react. Rss display issue

Tags: android, react-native, rss, rss-reader, react-android

I'm trying to write an application to my phone.
I use the code from the react-native-rss-parser example.

```
    import * as rssParser from 'react-native-rss-parser';
 
return fetch('http://www.kbgau.ru/rss.php')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    console.log(rss.title);
    console.log(rss.items.length);
  });
```

how to correctly display text from rss to Text from View
Need display item.title, item.link, item,enclosure url image
Help plz!!!

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of the response? Try to console it

I think it's because you fetch data from http

Try to fetch data from site that using https

Or you can try to set this on DEBUG mode

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24408#issuecomment-537081276

But, this settings isn't recommended for RELEASE mode, because it's a risk for security

Comment: Sorry, i use https. But questions was, how i can display information from rss, in components <text>

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I have tried this library, and it show all the data on console

Comment: Or don't you know how to set it to state?

Comment: `function News({ navigation }) {
  return fetch('https://kbgau.ru/rss.php')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    console.log(rss.items[0].description);
  });
} `

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.